# MySQL database backup plan

Tags: mysql, backup, disaster-recovery

I have a MySQL database that is about 17GB in size. Right now we don't have a backup for this and I have been tasked to look into backing it up automatically.

I am a software developer myself, not an expert database engineer.

After some research I found out that MySQL has something called *MySQL Replication*, which will automatically create a backup database on different server.

My concern about this is that if someone accidentally drops a table, or deletes a record, the same will happen on the slave database as well - so that would not serve as a backup.

I need suggestions on what can be done with our MySQL database so that it can be backed up automatically.

Comment: *After some research I found out that MySQL has something called MySQL Replication, which will automatically create a backup database on different server.* :ROFL: Replication initiation needs in restoring full DB backup on slave server.

Comment: How complex is your DB structure?

Comment: See also LVM snapshots.

Comment: @Akinam I have about 80 tables in 2 databases to backup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `mysqlbackup` is not a hot backup solution. For databases the size of your one, there really is no debate; see the related Q & A [Mysql backup strategies?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22612/mysql-backup-strategies)

As Shlomi Noach (GitHub's MySQL guy) says in his answer, [Percona's XtraBackup](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup) is your go-to choice. It is also worth reading [MySQL Backup and Restore Best Practices](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/mysql-backup-and-restore-best-practices) by Krzysztof Ksiazek.

By the way, **no backup strategy on earth** will protect you from devs/DBAs deleting records/dropping tables, that's why you should be using incremental backups; maybe [LVM snapshots](https://www.tecmint.com/take-snapshot-of-logical-volume-and-restore-in-lvm/) or [flush logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/backup-strategy-summary.html). However, incremental backups are also [performed](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/backup_scenarios/incremental_backup.html) by XtraBackup. See also [Example Backup and Recovery Strategy](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/backup-strategy-example.html) in the MySQL reference manual.

On a more general note, broad approaches to this issue are discussed in:

- [Database Backup and Recovery Best Practices](https://www.isaca.org/Journal/archives/2012/Volume-1/Pages/Database-Backup-and-Recovery-Best-Practices.aspx) by Ali Navid Akhtar, Jeff Buchholtz, Michael Ryan, and Kumar Setty
- [Backup and Recovery Best Practices](https://sqlbak.com/blog/backup-and-recovery-best-practices) by Omelchenko Alexander

In any case, on a production system, devs (or DBAs for that matter) should **not** be wandering through the filesystem and/or database deleting stuff *ad libitum*. **Any and all** changes on production should have been performed at least twice on test/UAT or similar systems before being implemented in prod! This is best practice.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It’s glad to be a member of such a great community. Will XtraBackup serve my purpose and do incremental backups? Also is it easy to implement for a non database expert like me ? Thanks

Comment: I have always found Percona's documentation to be **excellent**, and their lists are very helpful as well! There's always here also! If you found my answer good, you could always mark it as correct and/or helpful. Glad your first experience here has been positive!

Comment: I was reading the documentation for XtraBackup and it says that it doesnot support MYSQL versions less then 8.0. The version i am running right now is MySQL Version 5.6.43. What is your advise on this?

Comment: I was surprised about 5.6, so I checked. Percona is saying that 2.4 (latest version) [supports MySQL](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/index.html) the way back to version 5.1!

Comment: sorry I was looking at the version 8 of Percona.