# What is the use of ibdata1 file in mysql?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5

I have application which has the backend db as Mysql(InnoDb engine), and currently my client wants to decrease the size of the ibdata file to some fixed size. I found the three below solutions.

- Solution 1: `innodb_file_per_table`
- Solution 2: `innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:50M;ibdata2:50M:autoextend`
- Solution 3: `innodb_data_file_path=ibdata1:10M:autoextend:max:50M`

And I really dont have knowledge about the ibadata1 file, can anybody help me on this and I want to know whether is it safe to fix the ibdata size(solution 3) and what does the ibdata exactly for?

Answer (score 5):

In My Opinion you should use your **solution1**.

I am not very clear with what you will accomplish with the **solution2 and solution3.** with **innodb_file_per_table OFF** because they will never shrink the ibdata size whenever there delete,drop or truncate on an InnoDB table so using these option your ibdata will grow endlessly.

For your information have a look at this [way to reduce the size of ibdata in mysql.?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8982/is-there-any-best-way-to-reduce-the-size-of-ibdata-in-mysql.)

without using  `innodb_file_per_table`, the ibdata file never compresses or shrinks, Not when you delete a row, drop a table, or a database. In no time, 3GB of data can become a 20GB file if you have an active queuing system.

Have a look why to use innodb_file_per_table : [Reasons to use innodb_file_per_table.](http://code.openark.org/blog/mysql/reasons-to-use-innodb_file_per_table)