# Restoring data from dumped sql file gives: mysql: unknown option '--innodb_file_per_table

Tags: mysql, innodb

I was trying to separate DB indexes from `ibdata1` I took the steps in [what-is-the-best-way-to-reduce-the-size-of-ibdata-in-mysql](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8982/what-is-the-best-way-to-reduce-the-size-of-ibdata-in-mysql/8983#8983)

I dumped data, dropped databases, and started mysql service.

I got the following error and now I'm stuck:

```
mysql -u root -p < alldb.sql
mysql: unknown option '--innodb_file_per_table'
```

What is the solution now?

When I remove the below lines from `my.cnf` everything works fine:

```
[mysql]
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_log_file_size=1G
innodb_buffer_pool_size=4G
```

Why `innodb_file_per_table` is an unknown option?

The weired thing is that I can set `innodb_file_per_table` dynamically and it separates `.ibd` file when I alter them to InnoDB engine.

---

**EDIT:**
It should be an unknown option as I've put it below `[mysql]` not `[mysqld]`. I went through the process again and now it works just fine. `ibd` files are in their respective database folder.

Phew...

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: @DerekDowney, MySQL version is: 5.5.37

Comment: its located below `[mysql]` rather than `[mysqld]`. is it important?

Comment: Hmph, I swear I looked at `[mysql]` vs `[mysqld]`. Ah, I did...but you edited it earlier in the process...Oh well, glad you figured it out :)

Comment: @DerekDowney, I should have mentioned that in the EDIT part instead of replacing it with the new one, but thanks anyway. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved:

It should be an unknown option as I've put it below [mysql] not [mysqld]. I put all the parameters below `[mysqld]` and I went through the process again and now it works just fine. `ibd` files are in their respective database folder.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your my.cnf is missing the value for `innodb_file_per_table`. Try to add a value for the option, like this:

`innodb_file_per_table=1`

Comment: `mysql: unknown variable 'innodb_file_per_table=1'`

Comment: Is `innodb_file_format=Barracuda` set?

Comment: How to check that?

Comment: `SELECT @@innodb_file_per_table;` should return `1` and `SELECT @@innodb_file_format;` should return `Barracuda`