# MySQL Server Backup

Tags: mysql, backup, windows

I was wondering if there was any way of making a backup of an entire MySQL Server at regular intervals to a specific location. (If the version is required I can get it easily).

If there is, I must have a way of restoring just a single database from that server backup easily as though I have backed them up individually.

The method used will just be a pure backup and not a difference so no need to worry about complications.

UPDATE: I am using Windows Server 2008 to host the MySQL Server

Comment: InnoDB or MyISAM? Enterprise or Community? Can you use 3rd party tools?

Comment: @gbn InnoDB I'm pretty sure, and I would rather not use 3rd party tools unless it is impossible to do otherwise

Comment: A batch script that calls mysqldump is not good enough?

Comment: @pritaeas I'm not saying that it isn't good enough, I'm actually asking for any way to do it whatsoever, just to the requirements above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**PLEASE SEE MY WINDOWS ANSWER DOWN BELOW BY THE `UPDATE 2012-05-22 12:42 EDT`**

You need to make backups of each database separately

First, go get all your databases

```
MYSQL_CONN="-uusername -ppassword"
SQLSTMT="SELECT DISTINCT table_schema FROM information_schema.tables"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} WHERE table_schema NOT IN"
SQLSTMT="${SQLSTMT} ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" > /tmp/ListOfDatabases.txt
```

### BACKUP ALGORITHM #1

If you have a few databases to backup, you can dump all the databases is parallel:

```
MYSQL_CONN="-uusername -ppassword"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--hex-blob --routines --triggers"
for DB in `cat /tmp/ListOfDatabases.txt`
do
    BACKUP_GZIP=${DB}.sql.gz
    mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${DB} | gzip > ${BACKUP_GZIP} &
done
wait
```

### BACKUP ALGORITHM #2

If there are too many databases to launch at the same time, dump 10 at a time:

```
MYSQL_CONN="-uusername -ppassword"
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--hex-blob --routines --triggers"
COMMIT_COUNT=0
COMMIT_LIMIT=10
for DB in `cat /tmp/ListOfDatabases.txt`
do
    mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${DB} | gzip > ${DB}.sql.gz &
    (( COMMIT_COUNT++ ))
    if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -eq ${COMMIT_LIMIT} ]
    then
        COMMIT_COUNT=0
        wait
    fi
done
if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -gt 0 ]
then
    wait
fi
```

### BACKUP ALGORITHM #3

If there are simply way too many databases or the some of the databases are simply too large for frequent backups, you may want to think about making backups like this:

- On the 1st of the month, dump the Separate Databases Using `BACKUP ALGORITHM #2`
- Every hour, make copies to the binary logs (forming a binary log archive)

That way, restoration of a database can be done in a point-in-time fashion.

For example, to get database `mydb` as for 2012-05-20 09:00:00 you do this:

- Restore Database Backup from 2012-05-01 00:00:00
- Replay all archived binary logs using the mysqlbinlog program

  - use option `--start-datetime="2012-05-01 00:00:00"`
  - use option `--stop-datetime="2012-05-20 09:00:00"`
  - use option `--database=mydb`

### CONCLUSION

[*There may be other considerations to these scripts you may want to factor in. You may also want to use Open Source/Commerical programs to get the backups in the way most comfortable for you to use*](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2227/877).

I would further recommend using MySQL Replication. That way these scripts can be executed on the Slave in this manner (as recommended in [**MySQL 5.0 Certification Study Guide**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672328127), Page 462 Section 32.6 under the Heading "Replication as an Aid to Backup"):

- STOP SLAVE SQL_THREAD;
- Run the Backup
- START SLAVE SQL_THREAD;

This would also keep the backups from interefering with a production Master.

### **UPDATE 2012-05-22 12:42 EDT**

Oh, you are running Windows 2008? That is a whole different ballgame.

[**I actually wrote a post in StackOverflow on dumping separate databases in Windows**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9733345/491757) back in March of 2012.

I will post my answer from StackOverflow right now...

Have the information_schema database construct a DOS Batch File to perform the mysqldumps in parallel

```
set MYSQLUSER=root
set MYSQLPASS=1234
set BATCHFILE=S:\Backup\MySQL\Batch_mysqldump.bat 
set DUMPPATH=S:\Backup\MySQL
echo @echo off > %BATCHFILE% 
echo cd %DUMPPATH% >> %BATCHFILE% 
mysql -u%MYSQLUSER% -p%MYSQLPASS% -AN -e"SELECT CONCAT('start mysqldump -u%MYSQLUSER% -p%MYSQLPASS% --routines --triggers ',schema_name,' > ',schema_name,'.sql') FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','performance_schema')" >> %BATCHFILE% 
type %BATCHFILE%
```

Just run like any DOS Batch File

Make sure you have the correct username and password to connect to mysql

I just tried it out to make sure

```
C:\>set MYSQLUSER=lwdba

C:\>set MYSQLPASS=<hidden>

C:\>set BATCHFILE=C:\LWDBA\Batch_mysqldump.bat

C:\>set DUMPPATH=C:\LWDBA

C:\>echo @echo off > %BATCHFILE%

C:\>echo cd %DUMPPATH% >> %BATCHFILE%

C:\>mysql -u%MYSQLUSER% -p%MYSQLPASS% -AN -Bse"SELECT CONCAT('start mysqldump -u%MYSQLUSER% -p%MYSQLPASS% --routines --triggers ',schema_nam
e,' > ',schema_name,'.sql') FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','performance_schema')" >> %BATCH
FILE%

C:\>type %BATCHFILE%
@echo off
cd C:\LWDBA
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers a1ex07 > a1ex07.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers annarbor > annarbor.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers dilyan_kn > dilyan_kn.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers dtest > dtest.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers dude > dude.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers example > example.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers fed > fed.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers friends > friends.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers giannosfor > giannosfor.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers javier > javier.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers johnlocke > johnlocke.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers junk > junk.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers lovesh > lovesh.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers mysql > mysql.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers nwwatson > nwwatson.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers part > part.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers preeti > preeti.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers prefixdb > prefixdb.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers replagdb > replagdb.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers rollup_test > rollup_test.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers sample > sample.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers stuff > stuff.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers table_test > table_test.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers tagmediatest > tagmediatest.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers targetdb > targetdb.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers test > test.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers test_mysqldb > test_mysqldb.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers tostinni > tostinni.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers user1267617 > user1267617.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers user391986 > user391986.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers utility > utility.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers veto > veto.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers vito > vito.sql
start mysqldump -ulwdba -phidden  --routines --triggers zipcodes > zipcodes.sql
```

Give it a Try !!!

EDIT By JakeJ:

When ran, the solution just outputted the data into CMD, then closed it without writing it to any file, however this now saves the data to the .SQL file created.

```
set MYSQLUSER=root
set MYSQLPASS=pass
set BATCHFILE=C:\Backup\MySQL\Batch_mysqldump.bat 
set DUMPPATH=C:\Backup\MySQL
echo @echo off > %BATCHFILE% 
echo cd %DUMPPATH% >> %BATCHFILE% 
cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\
mysql.exe -u%MYSQLUSER% -p%MYSQLPASS% -AN -e"SELECT CONCAT('mysqldump -u%MYSQLUSER% -p%MYSQLPASS% --routines --triggers ',schema_name,' > ',schema_name,'.sql') FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','performance_schema')" >> %BATCHFILE% 
type %BATCHFILE% 
cd C:\Backup\MySQL
Batch_mysqldump.bat
```

Comment: EXREMELY detailed answer my friend, thank you for the answer, formatting and all. I really like the second backup method of only doing 10 at a time (I probably won't need it but good to keep in mind). Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I've tried various methods to run your scripts above but I can't get it to run. After some probing I've attained that it may be linux shell command but as I forgot to mention in the original post, the OS I am running the server on is Windows Server 2008. Unless I am wrong in what I'm saying, I cannot run this script

Comment: I just updated my answer to show how to do separate DB dumps in Windows using the information_schema database to create a DOS batch script to launch mysqldumps.

Comment: Just trying that out now, thanks for the update and sorry for missing that vital piece of information :P

Comment: Also, in your opinion, would it be easier to run a MySQL server on a linux machine?

Comment: Yes, because IMHO there is more scripting power available in the Linux shell. Of course, some hardcore Windows users would go with PowerShell.

Comment: I'll see if I can get the MySQL server hosted on a linux machine then instead, but for now time to get this version working

Comment: Your solution half-worked but I have it working now, I just had to remove the command 'start' as that seemed to just output the data into the CMD window instead of the file it creates, and I also made it change directory at the end and run the batch file it created. I will update the end of your post to show my batch file