# Issue with running multiple mysql commands in a bash for loop

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

I try to restore some .sql backups using a shell script with a for loop.

I run by `bash command.sh 'password'` using the command.sh below. However, when I typed it out, it didn't run and instead, mysql --help message showed up multiple times.. I think somehow the mysql command wasn't invoked. How to do it here?

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in *sql;
do
    fname=$(basename $i .sql)
    echo "working on $fname"
    mysql -uroot -p $1 $fname < $i
    wait
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Is something like this anything like what you want?

This is [how](http://danieldvork.in/script-for-mysql-backup-to-dropbox/) to run through all the databases in a server and backs them up.

```
#!/bin/bash

USER="your_user"
PASSWORD="your_password"
OUTPUT="/Users/rabino/DBs"

rm "$OUTPUT/*gz" > /dev/null 2>&1

databases=`mysql --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | tr -d "| " | grep -v Database`

for db in $databases; do
    if [[ "$db" != "information_schema" ]] && [[ "$db" != _* ]] ; then
        echo "Dumping database: $db"
        mysqldump --force --opt --user=$USER --password=$PASSWORD --databases $db > $OUTPUT/`date +%Y%m%d`.$db.sql
        gzip $OUTPUT/`date +%Y%m%d`.$db.sql
    fi
done
```

And in order to cycle through files of a particular type, you could look [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/).

As an example from this site, you could make use of this script

> Filename Expansion You can do [filename expansion in a loop](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/) such
>   as work on all pdf files in current directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.pdf
do
  echo "Removing password for pdf file - $f"
done
```

So, you want something like

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in *.sql
do
  echo "\nworking on filename"
  mysql -u root -ppassword < $f
  echo 
done
```

note: gap between -u and root, no gap between -p and password

Now, the script above isn't very sophisticated (and **untested**), but that combined with the database script above should give you stuff to work with. In any case, you can [Google](https://www.google.ie/#q=mysql+incremental+backup+bash+script) the terms here and similar and you'll get loads of stuff. A few more [bash backup scripts](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18260/mysql-server-backup/18272#18272) (Rolando is a **big** hitter on this forum).

Here's a post about a lot of [MySQL backup solutions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/102342/34007) that don't require bash.

Comment: Thanks so much! Could you explain why" gap between -u and root, no gap between -p and password"?

Comment: I ended up using Buttle Butkus's answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20751352/suppress-warning-messages-using-mysql-from-within-terminal-but-password-written

Comment: Yeah, well there are a million ways to do this stuff. Best of luck.

Comment: `-p` requires no space -- to distinguish between password being provided versus prompted for.  Other options (eg, `-u`) work with or without a space.