# Speeding up mysqldump / reload

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

Converting a large schema to file-per-table and I will be performing a mysqldump/reload with --all-databases. I have edited the my.cnf and changed "innod_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2" to speed up the load. I am planning to "SET GLOBAL innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct=0;" at some point before the dump. I am curious to know which combination of settings will get me the fastest dump and reload times?

SCHEMA stats:

26 myisam tables
413 innodb
~240GB of data

[--opt= --disable-keys; --extended-insert; --quick, etc]
--no-autocommit ??

vs prepending session vars like:
"SET autocommit=0; SET unique_checks=0; SET foreign_key_checks=0;"

Are the mysqldump options equivalent or not really?

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 5):

## ASPECT #1

While setting [**innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct) to 0 is good to do prior to a dump, you will have to wait until the dirty page count falls below 1% of the InnoDB Buffer Pool size. Here is how you can measure it:

```
SELECT ibp_dirty * 100 / ibp_blocks PercentageDirty FROM
(SELECT variable_value ibp_blocks
FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total') A,
(SELECT variable_value ibp_dirty
FROM information_schema.global_status
WHERE variable_name = 'Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty') B;
```

Keep running this report until `PercentageDirty` reaches close to 1.00. Perhaps you could just set `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct` to 0 one hour before the dump.

If you do not change `innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct`, a mysqldump will force a flush of dirty blocks involving the table you are dumping.

## ASPECT #2

You should not have to prepend `"SET autocommit=0; SET unique_checks=0; SET foreign_key_checks=0;"` because a mysqldump includes them at the beginning of the dump. Here is a sample mysqldump's header (Please note the two lines after `TIME_ZONE`)

```
-- MySQL dump 10.11
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: dbAccessData
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version       5.0.51a-community-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Current Database: `dbAccessData`
--

CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `dbAccessData` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 */;

USE `dbAccessData`;
```

## ASPECT #3

Please run this query

```
SELECT engine,count(1) table_count FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='mysql' GROUP BY table_schema;
```

I ran this and got 25 for MySQL 5.5.23. Since you have 26 you have only 1 tables outside the mysql schema. To find it, run this:

```
SELECT table_schema,count(1) table_count FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE engine='MyISAM' GROUP BY table_schema;
```

If you stop writing to the one lone table, you should be able to mysqldump all databases just fine.

## ASPECT #4

All the needed options for `--opt` are adequate. No need to alter it.

## ASPECT #5

You may want to dump the databases into different file: Please see my `Apr 17, 2011` post [How can I optimize a mysqldump of a large database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database/2227#2227) on how to script parallel mysqldumps.

Comment: mysql> select count(*) from tables where engine='myisam';
59

Comment: So I actually have 26 MyISAMs in my schema-- Thanks for your advice re: just using "--opt" and I will definitely flush the innodb pages!

Comment: ASPECT #2 - you mention `autocommit=0` and 2 other things, but only those 2 things are handled by `mysqldump` while `autocommit` - the most important one of them that would provide the biggest speedup - isn't, yet you lump it in.

Comment: your command said "aria" engine for me, which is weird, then i checked and it seems to be the information_schema stuff, should i change that to innodb as well?