# MySQL settings useful to speed up a mysqldump import

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.6, mysqldump, import

Recently I had to import a 7 Gb MySQL dump file to a MySQL 5.6 server.  The import took around 7 hours on a mono-core CPU with 1 Gb of RAM.

Someone else tested the import on a MySQL server which has, amongst others, the following settings:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G
query_cache_size = 300M
```

I'm a bit skeptical about the relevancy of these settings (and yes, I even think that [setting such a large query cache is bad](https://haydenjames.io/mysql-query-cache-size-performance/)). Would that make a difference? Aren't these settings used only when querying the database, and hence irrelevant for an import?

If yes, which settings should be set to speed up the import of a large dump file?

According to [the official documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html) these values should be set temporarily:

```
unique_checks = 0
foreign_key_checks = 0
```

I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67117/speeding-up-mysql-dumps-and-imports) that it should be set also

```
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
```

but I don't think it would help, because autocommit mode (flushing logs to disk for every insert) is already disabled by default in the mysqldump command (`--opt` option).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## SUGGESTION #1

No need to run `unique_checks = 0` and `foreign_key_checks = 0`. See my 3-year-old post [Speeding up mysqldump / reload](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44297/speeding-up-mysqldump-reload/44309#44309) (ASPECT #2 shows a standard header of a mysqldump. Lines 13 and 14 handle the disabling of those checks for you)

## SUGGESTION #2

Please note the InnoDB Architecture (Picture From Percona CTO Vadim Tkachenko)

[image: InnoDB Plumbing]

If you want to reload a MySQL Instance you should temporarily disable the Double Write Buffer.

#### STEP #1

Login to the Target Server and run

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_fast_shutdown = 0;
```

#### STEP #2

Restart mysqld by setting to [innodb_doublewrite to OFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_doublewrite)

```
service mysql restart --innodb-doublewrite=OFF --innodb-fast-shutdown=0
```

#### STEP #3

Load the mysqldump into the Target Server

#### STEP #4

Restart mysqld normally (Double Write buffer will be enabled again)

```
service mysql restart
```

Since the name "Double Write Buffer" implies two writes, InnoDB will only write data and indexes straight to the table files and bypass writing to the Double Write Buffer within `ibdata1`. Maybe this will double the import time (pun intended)

## SUGGESTION #3

The default [innodb_log_buffer_size is 8M](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_log_buffer_size). You need a bigger Log Buffer.

Please add this line to my.cnf under the `[mysqld]` group header

```
[mysqld]
innodb_log_buffer_size = 128M
```

Then, restart mysqld before the reload of the mysqldump.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Hey Rolando, one question about increasing `innodb_log_buffer_size` - should this be set lower for normal operation or is having it that large beneficial in general production use?  Is there any drawback to having it that large?