# Fastest way to do a mysqldump restore on Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, performance, restore, mysqldump, amazon-rds

We need to restore a database from a 7-Gb mysqldump file to a RDS Amazon instance. 
The full restore takes between 3 and 4 hours (probably because of network latency since the dump has to reside on a EC2), and it's too long for us. For reference, a restore to a local mysqld would take less than 30 minutes.

Is there a Amazon-related solution that would allow us to reduce the import time?

Questions about optimizing a mysqldump restore time have been asked before, such as:

- [Speeding up mysqldump / reload](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44297/speeding-up-mysqldump-reload)
- [MySQL any way to import a huge (32 GB) sql dump faster?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83125/mysql-any-way-to-import-a-huge-32-gb-sql-dump-faster)
- [Reasonable times for a mysqldump restore?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152749/reasonable-times-for-a-mysqldump-restore)
- [MySQL settings useful to speed up a mysqldump import](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/150962/mysql-settings-useful-to-speed-up-a-mysqldump-import)

However, this question is different because relates to a RDS instance, so:

- Additional constraints are applied, for instance some MySQL variables (e.g. `innodb_doublewrite`) cannot be changed to improve performances
- There may be some Amazon-native solution or product that would solve this issue easily and nicely

Comment: What RDS Instance type do you use? What Storage Type and Size do you use? Is it a new or already used instance? If it's a new instance (just launched) you should warn up storage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must now think in terms of the RDS Instance

- Provisoning more IOPs
- [Is it safe to use innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12611/is-it-safe-to-use-innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit-2/12612#12612)

  - Set innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
  - Set sync_binlog=0
- Since max_allowed_packet = 1M by default in Amazon RDS, this could cause mysqldump's multirow inserts (extended inserts) could fail. You may want to mysqldump the database with --skip-extended-insert. This will guarantee the data being inserted one-by-one, but the dump will be much larger and take longer to import.

Please read [What I learned while migrating a customer MySQL installation to Amazon RDS](https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/07/28/what-i-learned-while-migrating-a-customer-mysql-installation-to-amazon-rds/) from Percona's Blog for even deeper insights.