# Does mysqldump -all-databases include all objects

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

Does `mysqldump -all-databases` include all objects ?

I have to migrate all databases to new server.

Answer (score 26):

No mysqldump -all-databases does not include all objects

```
mysqldump --help

  -A, --all-databases Dump all the databases. This will be same as --databases
                      with all databases selected.
```

So mysqldump with --all-databases only dumps all the databases.

In order to migrate all the databases to a new server, you should take a complete backup :

**mysqldump an entire mysql instance**

```
mysqldump -h... -u... -p... --events --routines --triggers --all-databases > MySQLData.sql
```

The drawback is that backups created this way can only be reloaded into the same major release version of mysql that the mysqldump was generated with. In other words, a mysqldump --all-databases from a MySQL 5.0 database cannot be loaded in 5.1 or 5.5. The reason ? The mysql schema is totally different between major releases.

Here is the generic way to dump the SQL Grants for users that is readble and more portable

```
mysql -h... -u... -p... --skip-column-names -A -e"SELECT CONCAT('SHOW GRANTS FOR ''',user,'''@''',host,''';') FROM mysql.user WHERE user<>''" | mysql -h... -u... -p... --skip-column-names -A | sed 's/$/;/g' > MySQLGrants.sql
```

Have a look at answer from [**RolandoMySQLDBA** on How can I optimize a mysqldump of a large database ?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2227/877)

Comment: You forgot `--events`  which is needed in addition to `--routines` and `--triggers` and you also omitted `--single-transaction` to avoid locking tables unnecessarily.

Comment: Just to be sure it's clear, `--single-transaction` won't produce a consistent backup if there are MyISAM tables being written to while the backup runs. However, adding `--single-transaction` is a good idea if you're using all InnoDB and want to avoid blocking while `mysqldump` runs.

Comment: It includes databases like `mysql` which I cannot import them in AWS RDS, how to avoid exporting them?

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
       mysqldump 
--defaults-file=/something/backup.conf 
--single-transaction 
--opt 
--default-character-set=utf8  
--events 
--routines 
--triggers 
--all-databases 
| gzip -9 -c 
| sudo tee /backup/mysql/db_backup_ALL_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`.sql.gz 
> /dev/null
```

I added single transaction, opt, default charset, compress in gzip and a timestamp to the file.

You can also replace `-h -u -p` by:

```
--defaults-file=/something/backup.conf
```

and then inside the file:

```
[mysqldump]
user=YOUR_USER
password=YOUR_PASSWORD
```

Also, gzip 9 for max compression, and then sudo tee to avoid permissions issues (err 32 for e.g.). Dev null to avoid the tee to console.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add any relevant information to the existing answer.