# Are `--events` and `--routines` really needed to get a `mysqldump --all-databases` of an entire mysql instance?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, mysql-5.7

[Several](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2227/187104) [fine](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/46132/187104) [answers](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8780/187104) on here have already exquisitely argued that

```
mysqldump --hex-blob --events --routines --triggers  [...]  --all-databases
```

should be all *- modulo storage-engine considerations -* one needs to get a

> **mysqldump of an entire mysql instance** ... everything written in one file:
>   table structures, indexes, triggers, stored procedures, users,
>   encrypted passwords....

And I wanted to believe - and use - that; however, reading up on [the manpage of `mysqldump(1)` (for MySQL 5.7.27)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) I find that:

> - [`--events`, `-E`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_events)
>
>   *[...]*
>
>   If you require events to be created with their original timestamp attributes, do not use `--events`. Instead, dump and reload
>     the contents of the `mysql.event` table directly, using a MySQL account
>     that has appropriate
>     privileges for the `mysql` database.

... and that:

> - [`--routines`, `-R`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_routines)
>
>   *[...]*
>
>   If you require routines to be created with their original timestamp attributes, do not use `--routines`. Instead, dump and reload
>     the contents of the `mysql.proc` table directly, using a MySQL account
>     that has appropriate
>     privileges for the `mysql` database.

This leads me to believe that since `--all-databases` will also cause the `mysql` database to be included in the dump, and by that, the `mysql.event` and `mysql.proc` tables, that I would *not* have to include the `--events` and `--routines` options at all to arrive at an as-complete-as-possible dump.

What's more, *including* those options, I expect, would get me a less-than-complete dump instead because:

> The output generated by using `--events` contains `CREATE EVENT`
>   statements to create the events. However, these statements do not
>   include attributes such as the event creation and modification
>   timestamps, so when the events
>   are reloaded, they are created with timestamps equal to the reload time.

... and likewise:

> The output generated by using `--routines` contains `CREATE PROCEDURE` and
>   `CREATE FUNCTION` statements to create the routines. However, these
>   statements do not include attributes such as the routine creation and
>   modification timestamps, so when the routines are reloaded, they are
>   created with timestamps equal to the reload time.

Although, the `mysql` database would still *also* be included, so I'm not sure what the net effect combining `--events` and `--routines` with `--all-databases` will be in the resulting dump. I suspect it will depend on whether `mysql` will be dumped last, first, or somewhere in-between.

Does this reasoning make any sense or am I missing something?

Comment: Astute observations.

Comment: (Note that much of this discussion applies when using `--all-databases`.  Adjustments need to be made when thinking about dumping individual database(s).

Comment: @RickJames; the intent is to produce easily restorable, periodic instance dumps that get preserved with subsequent volume-snapshots, so `--all-databases` is definitely what I'm aiming for here.