# MySQL: ERROR 126 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table + slow logical backups

Tags: mysql, backup

I've got '/tmp' directory mounted with 'tmpfs' and for some reason this is causing the following error:

```
mysql> SELECT DISTINCT table_schema FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql')
    -> ;
ERROR 126 (HY000): Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_29ef_0.MYI'; try to repair it
```

-

```
# df -h /tmp/
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                 2.0G   12K  2.0G   1% /tmp
# df -i /tmp/
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
tmpfs                2041621       7 2041614    1% /tmp
# mount | grep /tmp
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,size=2048M)
```

Please note that the same query works fine when '/tmp' dir is mounted with ext4 file system.

**EDIT:**

Server_01

```
# cd /var/lib/mysql ; ls -lR | grep -c "\.frm$"
1876765
```

but this also happened on server with much less tables:

Server_02

```
# cd /var/lib/mysql ; ls -lR | grep -c "\.frm$"
49514
```

I was using this query to list all databases but as it didn't work with `tmpfs` I've just replaced it with simpler one (SHOW DATABASES...).

I was watching disk space on `/tmp` mounted with `tmpfs` and there still was a plenty of space so I'm not sure how it could run out of space?

Basically I've got a problem with logical backups on the server with ~8000 DBs - it takes many hours (~24) to complete this task. I've created a simple BASH script (please see below) and instead of `mysqldump` I'm using `mydumper` as initial tests showed that it's much faster.

Backups running very fast initially and then slowing down dramatically:

```
# ./backup.sh
Backing up database number: 1
Completed in: 0.016
Backing up database number: 2
Completed in: 0.078
Backing up database number: 3
Completed in: 0.074
Backing up database number: 4
Completed in: 0.068
Backing up database number: 5
Completed in: 0.071
Backing up database number: 6
Completed in: 0.060
Backing up database number: 7
Completed in: 0.067
Backing up database number: 8
Completed in: 0.070
Backing up database number: 9
Completed in: 0.065
.....
Backing up database number: 107
Completed in: 10.749
Backing up database number: 108
Completed in: 12.125
Backing up database number: 109
Completed in: 11.313
Backing up database number: 110
Completed in: 11.572
Backing up database number: 111
Completed in: 11.371
.....
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

DATA_DIR="/tmp/mysqlbackup"
LOCKFILE=/tmp/backup.lock
NOW=$(date +%Y%m%d)
COUNT=1

if [ -f "$LOCKFILE" ]; then
        echo "$(basename $0) is already running: PID $(cat $LOCKFILE)"
        exit 0

else

        echo $$ > $LOCKFILE

        if [ ! -d $DATA_DIR/$NOW ]; then
                mkdir -m 700 -p $DATA_DIR/$NOW
        fi

        while read DB; do

                (( COUNT++ ))

                echo "Backing up database number: $COUNT"

                START=$(date +%s.%N)

                mydumper -e -o $DATA_DIR/$NOW/$DB -B "$DB"

                ELAPSED=$(date +%s.%N)  

                printf "Completed in: %.3F\n" $(echo $ELAPSED - $START | bc)

        done <<< "$(mysql -A -B -N -e "SHOW DATABASES" | egrep -v '(mysql|*_schema|log)')"

        echo "Removing backup dir...";

        rm -rf $DATA_DIR/$NOW

        rm -f $LOCKFILE

        exit 0

fi
```

Comment: Please run the following Linux commands : `cd /var/lib/mysql ; ls -lR | grep -c "\.frm$"`. How many tables does it say it has ???

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ASPECT #1: BAD FILE

Something tells me you somehow ran out of space in `/tmpfs`.

Whenever MySQL creates a temp table

- It is created as a MyISAM table
- No `.frm` is created
- Initial `.MYD` is 0 bytes
- Initial `.MYI` is 1024 bytes (1K)
- There are never any indexes in the `.MYI`

I find that strange that MySQL could not create a 1K `.MYI`.

Since `ext3` has a default block size of 1K, while `ext4` has 4K, perhaps the 4K blocksize may have allowed for more data. This, in itself, is not the real problem.

## ASPECT #2: YOUR QUERY

If you have tens of thousands of tables, the query you are running looks quite demanding. In fact, the query says "Get me all databases that have 1 or more tables in them." If you have a large number of tables, you could be looking at a rather large temp table in order collect `table_schema` values before doing the `DISTINCT`.

Sometimes it is easy to forget

- [**the `SELECT DISTINCT` executes a `GROUP BY` internally**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/distinct-optimization.html)
- [This true in the older versions of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/distinct-optimization.html).

There are two Stackoverflow posts that mention this

- `Jun 06, 2012` : [How to select distinct rows without using group by statement (My Post)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10922650/491757)
- `Feb 24, 2009` : [What's faster, SELECT DISTINCT or GROUP BY in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/581530/491757)

## ANALYSIS

My guess is a combination of anomalies

**ANOMALY #1** : You have a large number of tables

**ANOMALY #2** : The temp table being made must have run out of space to have a damaged `.MYI`

**ANOMALY #3** : The query does not use an index.

Look at the table

```
mysql> show create table information_schema.tables\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: TABLES
Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `TABLES` (
  `TABLE_CATALOG` varchar(512) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TABLE_SCHEMA` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TABLE_NAME` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `TABLE_TYPE` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ENGINE` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VERSION` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `ROW_FORMAT` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TABLE_ROWS` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `AVG_ROW_LENGTH` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA_LENGTH` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `MAX_DATA_LENGTH` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `INDEX_LENGTH` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA_FREE` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `AUTO_INCREMENT` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATE_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `UPDATE_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `CHECK_TIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `TABLE_COLLATION` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CHECKSUM` bigint(21) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATE_OPTIONS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TABLE_COMMENT` varchar(2048) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
) ENGINE=MEMORY DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

A full table scan is required, resulting in the need for a temp table with an in-memory sort.

## SUGGESTIONS

**SUGGESTION #1** : Use `ext4`. You already said the query works fine in `ext4`.

**SUGGESTION #2** : Increase `tmpfs` to `16G`

**SUGGESTION #3** : Query the information_schema so that it does not use as much memory

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mysql.dbtbcount;
CREATE TABLE mysql.dbtbcount
(
    table_schema VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    table_count INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY (table_schema)
) ENGINE=MEMORY;
INSERT INTO mysql.dbtbcount (table_schema)
SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata
WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql'); 
INSERT INTO mysql.dbtbcount (table_schema)
SELECT table_schema FROM information_schema.tables
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE table_count = table_count + 1;
SELECT * FROM mysql.dbtbcount;
SELECT COUNT(1) DistinctDBs FROM mysql.dbtbcount WHERE table_count > 0;
```

This counts all tables in all databases

- When any row has a zero table_count, that database is empty.
- Count all rows that have a nonzero `table_count` to get the DISTINCT count.
- When done, run `DROP TABLE mysql.dbtbcount;`

## Give it a Try !!!

## UPDATE 2013-08-19 17:40 EDT

Your problem should have been posted as a separate question. Nevertheless, let's see what we can surmise from this.

You should not be using `/tmp` as a backup location. Why?

- The OS needs to write temp file there. At OS reboot, all files vanish from it. So, a transient folder should not be the place for backups.
- mysqld has [`/tmp` defined as the default folder for temp files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_tmpdir)

You need to reorganize the script to do parallel dumps

## SUGGESTION

You should collect the databases and parallel mysqldump 25 databases at a time, starting from the biggest databases to the smallest. It gets faster with each next set of 25...

```
BACKUP_FOLDER=/any/path/but/tmp

MYSQL_HOST=localhost
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-h${MYSQL_HOST} -u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"

SQLSTMT="SELECT db FROM (SELECT table_schema db,SUM(data_length) datasize"
SQLSTMT-"${SQLSTMT} FROM information_schema.tables"
SQLSTMT-"${SQLSTMT} WHERE table_schema NOT ('mysql','log')"
SQLSTMT-"${SQLSTMT} AND RIGHT(table_schema,7)<>'_schema'"
SQLSTMT-"${SQLSTMT} GROUP BY table_schema) A"
SQLSTMT-"${SQLSTMT} ORDER BY datasize DESC"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQLSTMT}" > /tmp/ListOfDatabases.txt

COMMIT_COUNT=0
COMMIT_LIMIT=25
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--hex-blob --routines --triggers"
for DB in `cat /tmp/ListOfDatabases.txt`
do
    BACKUP_FILE=${BACKUP_FOLDER}/${DB}.sql.gz
    mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${DB} | gzip > ${BACKUP_FILE} &
    (( COMMIT_COUNT++ ))
    if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -eq ${COMMIT_LIMIT} ]
    then
        COMMIT_COUNT=0
        wait
    fi
done
if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -gt 0 ]
then
    wait
fi
```

## UPDATE 2013-08-20 10:03 EDT

If you don't care about the size of the database here is an alternate method that will start the mysqldump process faster:

```
BACKUP_FOLDER=/any/path/but/tmp

MYSQL_HOST=localhost
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-h${MYSQL_HOST} -u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"

SQLSTMT-"${SQLSTMT} SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata"
SQLSTMT-"${SQLSTMT} WHERE schema_name NOT ('mysql','log')"
SQLSTMT-"${SQLSTMT} AND RIGHT(schema_name ,7)<>'_schema'"

COMMIT_COUNT=0
COMMIT_LIMIT=25
MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS="--hex-blob --routines --triggers"
for DB in `cat /tmp/ListOfDatabases.txt`
do
    BACKUP_FILE=${BACKUP_FOLDER}/${DB}.sql.gz
    mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${MYSQLDUMP_OPTIONS} ${DB} | gzip > ${BACKUP_FILE} &
    (( COMMIT_COUNT++ ))
    if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -eq ${COMMIT_LIMIT} ]
    then
        COMMIT_COUNT=0
        wait
    fi
done
if [ ${COMMIT_COUNT} -gt 0 ]
then
    wait
fi
```

I wrote about doing parallel database and table dumps before : [How can I optimize a mysqldump of a large database?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database/2227#2227)

If you cannot get `mydumper` to throttle based on database size, this is the way to go.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: Thanks for your great help as usually. I've updated question with the whole story behind this...

Comment: Do you know why `mydumper` spawns only one MySQL thread with your script another words it's not parallel?

Comment: This is only a guess: mydumper probably issues some locking that prevents multiple instances of mydumper because it is trying to do its own parallel execution.