# Restored database copy larger than original

Tags: mysql, innodb

I've created a copy of a database for testing. It's on the same server as the original. However, tables are listed as being larger on the restored copy than on the original.

My original database is 148 MB, the copy is 232 MB. Table 'message' is 15 MB on the original, 28 MB on the copy. (I'm using queries like https://stackoverflow.com/a/1733523/492455 to get these values).

The CREATE TABLE statements (SHOW CREATE TABLE) are identical on both databases (except for the AUTO_INCREMENT value). Here's one for a table (33 MB original size, 76 MB copied size:

```
CREATE TABLE `mdl_log` (
  `id` bigint(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `userid` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ip` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `course` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `module` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `cmid` bigint(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `action` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `url` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `info` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `mdl_log_coumodact_ix` (`course`,`module`,`action`),
  KEY `mdl_log_tim_ix` (`time`),
  KEY `mdl_log_act_ix` (`action`),
  KEY `mdl_log_usecou_ix` (`userid`,`course`),
  KEY `mdl_log_cmi_ix` (`cmid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=231557 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
COMMENT='Every action is logged as far as possible'
```

Can anyone suggest what's going on here?

MySQL Server v5.6.24 on CentOS 6.2.

Thanks,

Leon

Comment: mysql_user: it's UTF-8 on both the original and copied tables.

Answer (score 1):

You may find this surprising but this is something I have come to expect often. I have mentioned in other posts how data loaded in primary key order can populate BTREE indexes in a lopsided manner:

- `May 01, 2014` : [Why would the size of MySQL MyISAM table indexes (aka MYI file) not match after mysqldump import?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64230/why-would-the-size-of-mysql-myisam-table-indexes-aka-myi-file-not-match-after/64267#64267)
- `Dec 28, 2014` : [What are the optimal mysqldump settings?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/87100/what-are-the-optimal-mysqldump-settings/87117#87117) (See the CAVEAT about `--order-by-primary`)

This behavior is seen for MyISAM and InnoDB alike. Don't be too alarmed by this. If the data being copied is in order by an auto-incremented primary key when dumping, the clustered index is populated in a lopsided manner from inception.

When it comes to InnoDB, bulking loading data into a table with an index will have a degree of fragmentation introduced. You just have to bite the bullet on this.

To minimize this, you should do the following for table mytable:

- Copy the table schema for mytable
- Create empty `mytable` on target server
- Drop indexes for `mytable` on target server
- Load data into `mytable` on target server
- Create all indexes

MyISAM already has this paradigm in place for non-unique indexes when reloading MyISAM tables

- ALTER TABLE mytable DISABLE KEYS;
- Load the data
- ALTER TABLE mytable ENABLE KEYS;

InnoDB does not :-(

## CONCLUSION

Your main concern should be the content of data.

You should run `pt-table-checksum` for the table for both source and target servers. Even with mismatches here, do not worry too much with VARCHAR columns (See my post [Native checksum table says there's a difference, pt-table-checksum does not](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60979/native-checksum-table-says-theres-a-difference-pt-table-checksum-does-not/60980#60980)).

You could also just dump the data in a specific into CSV files on source and target servers and compare the text just to inspect content.

In closing, even though the table is small, once the copy is done and the table is not corrupt, try what you reasonably can to defragment your tables and just live with it.

Comment: Surely this means that the additional size due to unbalanced B-trees is taken up by the indexes and if I dropped these I would recover this space. But if I drop indexes (so index_length is 0) my data_length is still much larger than the original (28 MB vs 14 MB). If I've understood your explanation dropping the indexes should result in a table at least as small as the original which is not what I see.