# Best way to backup mysql database?

Tags: mysql, backup

How do you backup your mysql database so you can be sure that you are 100% protected of data loss whatever problems that may happen? I am thinking to rent one or two servers that i will use only for backup. Then i will setup rsync cron jobs that will do incremental backups daily to these two servers. Will this be enough? Do you use other methods than rsync to backup you database?

Comment: Rsync? Of the actual MySQL data files from a running server? That's not an acceptable method of backup.

Comment: The mysql data files from mysqldump.

Comment: See my post http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-optimize-a-mysqldump-of-a-large-database/2227#2227

Answer (score 3):

In my biased opinion (I'm author of TwinDB) the best way to take backups from MySQL is to use [TwinDB](https://console.twindb.com/). Not only it will save from blunders like rsyncing database files (which with 100% guarantee leads to corrupted tablespace) but also lets you take incremental copies correctly.