# How to implement effective MySQL database backup mechanisms?

Tags: mysql, backup

MySQL database backup is really critical for my company's business, can anyone share some experience on this?

Comment: What have you found yourself? what area's are critical? is it the data/consistency/uptime.. I think with some common sense you can devise a plan that suits your companies needs, otherwise hire a database consultant to do this for you

Comment: What are you doing at the moment to ensure data integrity and security? Maybe if you explained this, we could tell you what you could/should be doing (more) and/or what you're doing wrong?

Comment: More answers:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2853/1876

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now we are using cloud database services from Alibaba Cloud. But I need to figure out the strategy for backup and recovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is `mysqldump`. Something like the following should get it done:

`mysqldump -u root -p --databases DB_NAME > databasename.sql`